# Installing Raspbian in Android phone

Tags: raspbian

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I have a 4.4.4 KitKat Android smartphone. I wish to install Raspbian in this smartphone. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Does your smartphone come with a Broadcom BCM283X SoC? Raspbian is just a Debian that specifically aims at those SoCs.

Comment: The answer, i believe, is "no", but this might be an x-y problem. What do you actually want to do? There are several ways to do linux things on Android, depending on what it is you really want to do. (Likely most of them will be of topic for a Raspberry Pi forum however.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no.

Longer answer is that Raspbian is basically a Debian based OS optimized for Raspberry Pi devices only. If you wish to have similar experience to this system, there are several solutions for Android phones to run virtualized Debian environment or even installing it as secondary system - though finding proper drivers might be an issue that needs to be addressed for every phone model separately.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of possible.

Android's use of the Linux kernel means it can run Raspbian userspace in a (very porous) chroot jail right alongside Android.

This is a supremely sub-optimal and weird way to run Raspbian but I have an APK installer that takes a lot of manual steps out of the process, [here](https://github.com/DesktopECHO/Pi-hole-for-Android).

[image: Deployment is ready]

RDP Session to Raspbian instance on Moto G7 running PIXEL Desktop:
[image: RDP To PIXEL Desktop]